# SQL: nest SUM with MN

Tags: sql

I have a simple SQL statement like the following and I would like to nest the aggregate functions `SUM` and `MIN`:

```
SELECT SUM(MIN(r1.price)) 
FROM rounds r1, rounds r2 
WHERE r1.round ='1' 
AND r1.market = r2.market 
AND r1.round = r2.round 
AND r1.name = r2.name 
GROUP BY market
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work.

Comment: please add what sql service you are using (oracle, postgres, mssql...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT SUM(lowest_price) FROM
(SELECT MIN(r1.price) AS lowest_price 
FROM rounds r1
INNER JOIN rounds r2 ON r1.market = r2.market
                    AND r1.round = r2.round 
                    AND r1.name = r2.name
WHERE r1.round ='1' 
GROUP BY r1.market) innerSElect
```

Comment: 3 FROM, 2 select somethings off I think

Comment: Yes one FROM is too much in line 2, but the rest works like a charm, thank you guy ;)

Answer (score 1):

If your chosen server product's SQL flavour supports ranking functions, you could also use a query like this:

```
SELECT SUM(price)
FROM (
  SELECT
    r1.price,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY r1.market ORDER BY r1.price) AS rnk
  FROM rounds r1
    INNER JOIN rounds r2 ON r1.market = r2.market 
                        AND r1.round  = r2.round 
                        AND r1.name   = r2.name 
  WHERE r1.round = '1' 
) s
WHERE rnk = 1
```